# Differential Equations whose solution is the family of circles with fixed radius and tangent to a common line

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, circles

***Q.*** The differential equation of the family of circles with fixed radius **5 units** and centre on the line **y = 2** is?

---

My Attempt:
I can write the equation of a random circle, satisfying the condition mentioned in the question, as:
$$(x – h)^2 + (y – 2)^2 = 25$$

Differentiating, with respect to x,

$$2(x – h) + 2(y – 2) \frac{dy}{dx}= 0$$

I am not sure how to proceed further.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you eliminate the arbitrary constant $h$ from your system of equations? That will give you the answer.

Comment: If I find value of 'h' from second equation and substitute into first, will it do?

Comment: Yes, it will do. Although you might consider replacing the complete term $(x-h)$

Comment: I would leave the $h$ in there.

Comment: @tomi I guess 'h' being the arbitrary constant will have to be removed. I am not too sure what you meant by your comment.

Answer (score -1):

Rearrange your equation:

$$2(y-2)\frac {dy}{dx}=-2(x-h)$$

$$\frac {dy}{dx}=-\frac{(x-h)}{(y-2)}$$

Comment: This has any half-circle with center $(h,2)$ as solution, not just those with radius $5$.